# in as function name gives error

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am building a Phonegap based Android Application in which I have created a function named in  but when I run application, on console it gives below error:

SyntaxError: Parse error at file:///android_asset/www/Clause.js:59

```
function Clause() {
    this.in = function() {}
}
```

Comment: Is their work around to use in as function name, I also want to use delete as function name but same problem their also, is their any solution??

Comment: You can use In or IN or _in or even a name that gives a little more information than 'in'...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bracket notation to set and access reserved words as property names.

```
function Clause() {
    this['in'] = function() {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`in` is a reserved word in JavaScript.

It can be used for iterating over the properties of an object like:

```
for(var prop in obj) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Is their work around to use in as function name, I also want to use delete as function name but same problem their also, is their any solution??